# facing issue when installing or uninstalling any plugin android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I am facing issue when installing or uninstalling any plugin android studio.

Because of this i cant install any of useful plugins like parcelable or adb.

I am stuck with this. ;(

- When ever i try uninstalling plugin, it works and ask restart android studio? 
  But when studio restarts, i find plugin again there.
- Same for installing any new plugin, when i install new one, same studio restarts. but i cant find new plugin in settings>plugins.

Please tell some solution if some one knows.

Comment: Check the [logs for errors](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085), see if the plugin is present in the [plugins directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).